# How do i find the surface of the triangle?(with a graphic and a x,y coordinate table)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

How do i find the surface of the triangle ASB?(with a graphic and a x,y coordinate table)

[image]               [image]

Comment: If you have the three coordinates you can use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the three side lengths, then use Heron's equation.  By the way:  You *do* realize that the parabola and straight line and all that labelling in your figure are irrelevant... a distraction... right?

Comment: 1.Do you mean "surface area"?  2.How does the co-ordinate table relate to the graphic?  3.What have you tried? What difficulty are you having with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the tabled coordinates, the equation of the parabola is obtained as

$$y=-(x-3)^2+4$$

Then, the vertexes are $A(1,0)$, $B(4,3)$ and $S(3,4)$. Apply the triangle area formula with  coordinates below

$$\begin{align}
Area &= \frac12|x_A(y_B-y_S) + x_B(y_S-y_A) + x_S(y_A-y_B)|\\
&= \frac12|1(3-4) + 4(4-0) + 3(0-3)| =3
\end{align}$$

Comment: how did you find (h,k)

Comment: @0_0 Assume $y-k=a(x-h)^2$. Plug in the 3 points in the table to solve for a, k and h

Answer (score 1):

First you have to determine the equation of the parabola, and based on that you determine the points A = (a, 0) and B = (4, b). I suppose that S = (3,4).

Answer (score 0):

1. Rule of the function: $$f(x)=-x^2+6x-5$$
2. Find coordinates of A, B, S:

For S:

$$f'(x)=-2x+6$$
$$0=-2x+6$$
$$x=3$$

By replacing to get y, we get: $$y=4$$

so, $S=(3,4)$

For A:

By plugging in $y=0$:

$$0=-x^2+6x-5$$
$$x_1=1, x_2=5$$

We choose x=1 in this case because of A's position on the graph

so, $A=(1,0)$

For B:

We know x=4, so $$f(4)=-16+24-5$$
$$y=3$$

so, $B=(4,3)$

3. Find the measurement of the segments:

$$(AB)^2=3^2+3^2$$
$$AB=3\sqrt2$$

$$ $$
$$(SB)^2=1^2+1^2$$
$$SB=\sqrt2$$

$$ $$
$$(SA)^2=2^2+4^2$$
$$SA=2\sqrt5$$

4. Using Heron's law:

$$A=\sqrt{s(s-SA)(s-SB)(s-AB)}$$

where s = half the perimeter of the triangle

$$A=\sqrt{5(5-2\sqrt5)(5-\sqrt2)(5-3\sqrt2)}$$

so, $$A=2.7u^2$$

Comment: Observe  $$s=2\sqrt 2+ \sqrt 5\neq 5$$